# Haskell get types of Data Constructor

Tags: haskell, introspection

I was wondering if given a constructor, such as:

```
data UserType = User
  { username :: String
  , password :: String
  } -- deriving whatever necessary
```

What the easiest way is for me to get something on the lines of `[("username", String), ("password", String)]`, short of just manually writing it. Now for this specific example it is fine to just write it but for a complex database model with lots of different fields it would be pretty annoying.

So far I have looked through `Typeable` and `Data` but so far the closest thing I have found is:

```
user = User "admin" "pass"
constrFields (toConstr user)
```

But that doesn't tell me the types, it just returns `["username", "password"]` and it also requires that I create an instance of User.

Comment: What is `[("username", String), ("password", String)]`? A type level list of pairs? Did you mean `[("username", "String"), ("password", "String")]` or something similar?

Comment: @Zeta I mean a string would work OK, but I phrased it that way because it could also be a more meaningful type. Such as something similar to `Data.Data.Constr` which can be inspected with other functions from `Data.Data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just knocked out a function using `Data.Typeable` that lets you turn a constructor into a list of the `TypeRep`s of its arguments. In conjunction with the `constrFields` you found you can zip them together to get your desired result:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

module Foo where
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Typeable.Internal(funTc)

getConsArguments c = go (typeOf c)
   where go x = let (con, rest) = splitTyConApp x    
                in if con == funTc         
                   then case rest of (c:cs:[]) -> c : go cs
                                     _ -> error "arrows always take two arguments"
                   else []
```

given `data Foo = Foo {a :: String, b :: Int} deriving Typeable`, we get

```
*> getConsArguments Foo
[[Char],Int]
```

As one would hope.

---

On how to get the field names without using a populated data type value itself, here is a solution:

```
constrFields . head . dataTypeConstrs $ dataTypeOf (undefined :: Foo)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `Typeable` is likely to change *substantially* in GHC 8.2, and this may well need to be changed then.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind showing me how you can also get the names of the fields. I know my example got those but I would love to be able to do it without creating an instance. Also how does this even work? When I do `:t` it says it is looking for a `Typeable a` but I thought the constructor was a function and the instance was the `Typeable a`, yet it lets me pass in the constructor.

Comment: @semicolon edited to show that portion of the solution. As to how it works,  we are using Typeable to get the type _of the constructor function_ then inducting on it to turn it into a list of its arguments.

Comment: @sclv Alright that makes a lot of sense thanks. Also I realized that you don't actually need to derive Typeable, as it is the fact that Foo is a function and functions derive Typeable that makes the whole thing work, which makes a lot of sense, as I was still pretty confused about that whole thing. And the undefined cheat is pretty sweet.